# iOS Sending BOOL value to server using JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, boolean

I am basically trying to do this;

```
// Catch the true/false flag and convert to BOOL value for server
NSString *on = [prefs objectForKey:@"published"];
BOOL flag = TRUE;
if ([on isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
{
    flag = TRUE;
} 
else 
{
    flag = FALSE;
}

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:body, flag, user_token, request_token, deviceID, api_user, nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"selections", @"published", @"user_token", @"request_token", @"device_id", @"api_user", nil];
NSDictionary *questionDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Which checks if the prefs is true and if so converts to BOOL value with true etc..

However it's crashing saying it's missing count of objects to keys.

Any help with doing this?

Comment: it's basically says that one of your objects in array 'objects' is nil, be sure to check this array by nslogging

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot add primitives to `NSArray` - Cocoa collections can contain only objects. Wrap your `flag` in an `NSNumber` to comply with this requirement, like this:

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:body, [NSNumber numberWithBool:flag], user_token, request_token, deviceID, api_user, nil];
```

You can also use the new syntax for arrays and values to shorten your code:

```
NSArray *objects = @[body, @(flag), user_token, request_token, deviceID, api_user];
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks very much, great for future reference :-)

Comment: NSArray *objects = @[@(flag), user_token, request_token, deviceID, api_user]; Is a shorter version of the above answer.

Comment: @AdamRush : more reading: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsnumber.html

Comment: dasblinkenlight there is no need for the 'nil'-sentinel. (last nil in the array). (when using the new syntax)